# Nested attributes для связи многии ко многим в Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Здравствуйте, я новичёк в ruby on rails. Есть задание сделать для для двух таблиц: books и creators, связанных через третью book_creators, сделать так, чтобы можно было создавать автора при создании книги и редактировать при, соответственно, редактировании книги, с использованием nested attributes. в форме для книг сделал чере fields_for.

При создании новой книги выдает ошибку: "Автор не может быть пустым"(из @book.book_creators.create!()), что логично ведь я его нигде не создаю... От сюда вопрос: Как мне его создать? Не пинайте сильно за очень тривиальный вопрос... Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Мои модели для таблиц:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stilage
  has_many :book_creators, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :book
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_creators, allow_destroy: true
end

class BookCreator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book, inverse_of: :book_creators
  belongs_to :creator, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :book_creators

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :creator, allow_destroy: true
end

class Creator < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :book_creators, inverse_of: :creator
end
```

Мой код в контролере книги:

```
def new
  @book = Book.new
  @book_creator = @book.book_creators.build
end

def create
  @book = Book.new(book_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @book.save
      format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @book }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:book_name, :part, :isbn_index, :publick_year, :number_of_have, :schelf_number, :stilage_id, 
  {book_creators_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :creator_id, :book_id, 
  creator_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :last_name, :first_name, :second_name]]}
  )
end
```

Код views книги:

```
  =f.fields_for :book_creator do |fr|
    = fr.hidden_field :id
    = fr.fields_for :creator do |fm|
      = fm.hidden_field :id
        .col-md-6
          .panel.panel-success
            .panel-heading
              Автор
              = i + 1
          .panel-body
            .row
              .col-md-6
                .form-group
                  = fm.label :Фамилия
                  = fm.text_field:last_name, class: 'form-control'
            .row
              .col-md-6
                .form-group
                   = fm.label :Имя
                   = fm.text_field:first_name, class: 'form-control'
            .row
              .col-md-6
                .form-group
                  = fm.label :Отчество
                  = fm.text_field:second_name, class: 'form-control'
```

Comment: А зачем вам эта строчка? `@book.book_creators.create!()` Вам в `new` надо `@book.book_creators.build`

Comment: Было раньше. Но насколько я понял @book.book_creators.build, сам по себе создает, но не сохраняет объект бд. Осознаю, что чтобы сохранить надо потом сделать .save, на созданный объект, но в моем случае разницы не будет, тк сохранить его мне не дадут валидации без созданного и внесенного в book_creators автора.

Comment: так вы же его в форме (вьюхе) и будете вносить, он и сохранится

Comment: Так ладно, тогда я совсем запутолся, прикреплю еще код формы на всякий случай

Comment: Изменил, код как было предложено выше. Нет, так же как было раньше: книга сохраняется, автор и book_creators нет

Comment: [Эта статья от Thoughtbot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through) определённо про этот случай.

Comment: @D-side, благодарю. Буду читать, разбираться. Просто замена на through, по образцу, пока. Видимо ошибка где-то в форме. Найду, надеюсь)